# How to access property by fetching in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I fetch data in serverside,I can get data.But when I set properties and pass them to

`/quiz-data`

```
const API_KEY="https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&type=multiple";
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const Quiz=require("../public/javascripts/quiz");

module.exports={
    getQuiz:function(res){
      fetch(API_KEY)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => { const quiz = new Quiz(json); 
            res.send({
                quiz,
                getNumOfQuiz:quiz.getNumOfQuiz(1),
                getCategory:quiz.getCategory(1),
                getDifficulty:quiz.getDifficulty(1),
                getQuestion:quiz.getQuestion(1),
                getAnswers:quiz.getAnswers(1)
            });
        });
    }
};
```

When I access`/quiz-data` I can get following data.

```
{"quiz":{"_quizzes":[{"category":"Entertainment: Film","type":"multiple","difficulty":"medium","question":"What type of cheese, loved by Wallace and Gromit, had it&#039;s sale prices rise after their successful short films?","correct_answer":"Wensleydale","incorrect_answers":["Cheddar","Moon Cheese","Edam"]}],"_correctAnswersNum":0},"getNumOfQuiz":1,"getCategory":"Entertainment: Film","getDifficulty":"medium","getQuestion":"What type of cheese, loved by Wallace and Gromit, had it&#039;s sale prices rise after their successful short films?","getAnswers":["Edam","Wensleydale","Cheddar","Moon Cheese"]}
```

But when I fetch in `clientside` by following

```
(()=>{
      
      const url = "/quiz-data";
      
      console.log("main.js was loaded");
      
      fetch(url)
      .then(response=>console.log(response.getCategory))
    //  .then(response => displayQuiz(response,1))

})();
```

I suffer following one.

`undefined`

I have set such properties. why I couldn't catch such properties..

Are there any way to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to call `response.json()`

Comment: `.then(response => response.json()).then(response => console.log(response.getCategory))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the fields of a json with fetch, you have to call response. json () in the second promise, then make another promise to get the return value of that one, in which case you can finally read the property

To do so with your example

```
(()=>{
      
      const url = "/quiz-data";
      
      console.log("main.js was loaded");
      
      fetch(url)
      .then(response=>response. json ())
      .then(response => displayQuiz(response.getCategory,1))

})();
```